# Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop in skill section of my personal portfolio

Tags: reactjs

**I can't resolve this bug. This is my code. Please help me with this. I tried changing fragments to div and provide it with a key but that didn't work either. proper keys are provided at required locations.**

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWc1N.png


  return (
    <>
              <motion.div className="app__skills-exp-works">
                {experience.works.map((work) => (
                  <>
                    <motion.div
                      whileInView={{ opacity: [0, 1] }}
                      transition={{ duration: 0.5 }}
                      className="app__skills-exp-work"
                      data-tip
                      data-for={work.name}
                      key={work.name}
                    >
                      <h4 className="bold-text">{work.name}</h4>
                      <p className="p-text">{work.company}</p>
                    </motion.div>
                    <ReactTooltip
                      id={work.name}
                      effect="solid"
                      arrowColor="#fff"
                      className="skills-tooltip"
                    >
                      {work.desc}
                    </ReactTooltip>
                  </>
                ))}
              </motion.div>
            </motion.div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default AppWrap(
  MotionWrap(Skills, 'app__skills'),
  'skills',
  'app__whitebg',
);
```

Comment: provide a key to the main view in the map function. u can use the index.

Answer (score 1):

instead of empty fragment you can use `<React.Fragment key={i}>`